# pimp shots -- what does that mean?

Tags: meaning

From the movie [Exists (2014)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1988621/):

> Usually when you put a GoPro camera inside of this casing, it doesn't focus very well underwater. So I went out and I bought one of these bad boys. That's gonna help me focus underwater because it's got a flat lens. So we're pretty much gonna get some **pimp shots** underwater today.

I searched online. Couldn't find anything as to what it means. So, maybe you guys can help me fugure out what *pimp shots* are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Pimp shot" is not a phrase as such. You have to consider on one side the adjective :

- **pimp** which is slang for "very good", "stylish", "awesome"....

and on the other the noun :

- **shot** which in the context you give is a photograph.

So "pimp shots" here means "awesome photos".

Comment: Is adjective "pimp" related to the verb *to pimp*, as in 'pimp my ride'?

Comment: Yes. Both being related to the noun pimp, which means someone who "manages" prostitutes. In short: it's not really a word one should use in formal situations.